# Got this reply after a pull request. What to do?

Tags: git, github

I created a pull request on a repository and got this reply how can i fix this? I think i accidentally did git merge couple of times without knowing it.
I got reply saying:
'You shouldn't need Merge branch 'gajabaar:main' into main on your merge history. Please fix that.'

[CLick here for the reply anc commit history.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Ix9.jpg)

Can i use

```
git revert /commit hash/
```

or

```
git checkout
```

What should i do?

Comment: Show the complete log of your PR branch please.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do depends on the contents of the 2 commits inside your pull request. `git checkout` and `git revert` don't necessarily solve your problem on their own.

If the changes of both commits (`Merge branch gajabaar:main into main` and `complete setup task`) are needed you can just squash them into a single commit. This will preserve all changes but you only have one commit in your pull request.

For this you can do the following:

1. Check out the branch of your pull request (`git checkout -b <your-branch-name>`)
2. Start an interactive rebase with `git rebase -i HEAD~2`. Your default editor will open and show something similar to this:

```
pick ce493b4 complete setup task
pick 0c3f6f9 Merge branch gajabaar:main into main

# Rebase eddd050..0c3f6f9 onto eddd050 (2 commands)
```

3. Change the line containing your merge commit to start with `squash` and save the change.
4. After saving your view should update and you can choose the desired commit message, just add `#` to the message you **don't** want (so in front of the merge message)

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# This is the 1st commit message:

complete setup task

# This is the commit message #2:

Merge branch gajabaar:main into main

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
```

Afterwards you can push your changes to the branch and the pull request should now only contain a single commit.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase for more indepth documentation.